# Format json data for Flotcharts

Tags: jquery

I am using Flowcharts and need to format JSON data from PHP post. The format I need is as follows:

```
[2, 16, 0, 12, 22, 5, -10, 5, 15, 2, 11, 55]
```

The javascript command to render the charts:

```
_initSparklineChart($('#kt_chart_sales_by_apps_1_2'), [2, 16, 0, 12, 22, 5, -10, 5, 15, 2, 11 , 66], KTApp.getStateColor('danger'), 2);
```

I am getting the data using a post like this:

```
for ($y = 1; $y <= 4; $y++) {       
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {    
        $array[$y][$x] = rand(1,100);       
    }    
}

$returnArray["message"]     = "Data Retrieved";
$returnArray["data"]        = $array;
$returnArray["count"]       = $count;

echo json_encode($returnArray);
```

So the javascript code would be something like this. Can anybody help me with this?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./demo2/widgets/functions/production.php",
    data: {mode:mode,date:date},
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
        var dataset1 = response["data"];

        var dataset2 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < dataset1.length; i++) {
            console.log(dataset1[i]);
            dataset2.push([dataset1[i]]);
        }

        _initSparklineChart($('#kt_chart_sales_by_apps_1_1'), [dataset2], KTApp.getStateColor('success'), 2);
    }
});
```

**Working JS**

```
var DataSet1    = {};
var DataSet2    = {};

$.each(response["data"], function( index, value ) {

    $.each(value, function( key, val ) {

        DataSet1[key] = val;  

    });

    DataSet2[index] = Object.values(DataSet1);  

});

$.each(DataSet2, function( index, value ) {

    _initSparklineChart($('#kt_chart_sales_by_apps_1_'+index), value, KTApp.getStateColor('success'), 2);

});
```

Comment: Your `response["data"]` is an object containing 4 objects each with 12 key/val pairs, whereas the format you say you need is an array of 10 numbers. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I need to convert the data to create 4 charts each with 10 values. I will edit the code with what I managed to achieve , at the moment it works but not sure if there is a better solution...

Comment: Where's the "10 values" requirement coming from? When you're generating the data you're using 12: `for ($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++)`, so how do you go from that to 10?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake... it should be 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure what you're asking, but from what I gather you want to initialise several charts, e.g. `#kt_chart_sales_by_apps_1_1`, `#kt_chart_sales_by_apps_1_2`, `#kt_chart_sales_by_apps_1_3`, etc.

If so, the following should work in your `success` callback:

```
success: function(response) {
    var datasets = response["data"];

    for (var set in datasets) {
        _initSparklineChart($('#kt_chart_sales_by_apps_1_'+set), datasets[set], KTApp.getStateColor('success'), 2);
    }
}
```

Small example:

```js
var datasets = {
    "1": [2, 16, 0, 12, 22, 5, -10, 5, 15, 2, 11 , 66],
    "2": [12, 11, 5, 22, 16, -10, 66, 5, 2, 2, 15, 0],
    "3": [5, 0, 11, 2, 15, 12, 2, 66, 5, -10, 22, 16],
    "4": [5, -10, 0, 2, 16, 22, 66, 12, 5, 15, 2, 11]
}

for (var set in datasets) {
    console.log("Using ID: #kt_chart_sales_by_apps_1_" + set, "with data set:", datasets[set]);
}
```